# Trouble loading data for train labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, macos-sierra

Trying to load data from a zip file however cannot get data from DataFrame.
Usually used to importing modules but this file is saved locally.

I've tried implementing different methods but cant seem to get very far.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd_data = pd.read_csv('inventory.zip')

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = pd_data.load_data(num_words=5000)
```

Comment: hint: your file has a `zip` extension but you're trying to read it as `csv`.

Comment: Check that you have an updated version of `pandas` and that there's only one `csv` file inside the `zip`. Otherwise, it won't work

Comment: Usually, I would do this: from keras.datasets import reuters

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=50000)  . Not sure what to do when files are stored locally

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to read a zip file, you should use the `compression` parameter

```
pd_data = pd.read_csv('inventory.zip', compression='zip')
```

An important assumption here is that the data that is compressed IS a .csv file.